# Semi asynchronous code logic

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, go, goroutine

I'm struggling to figure out a working design that would mix together synchronous flow with asynchronous behavior.

I've 4 components:

1. Seeder
2. Worker
3. Publisher
4. Updater

The only limitation I've is that once Seeder seeds data it must be blocked up until Updater is not fully finished with processing all tasks. The first 3 components could easily be synchronous but the Updater must work in parallel or it would take forever to finish the tasks.

So the flow is:

`Seeder -> Worker -> Publisher -> Updater --> Seeder -> Worker -> Publisher -> Updater ...`

and this flow must rotate forever.

The seeding and updating is towards a database. Unfortunately this particular database doesn't allow for a different design.

The best I got to is using `sync.WaitGroup` to sync the Updater goroutines and leave everything else in a synchronous state. The data to the Updater are provided through a channel.

Here is a simplified code (no errors, not much logic in).

```
func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    c := make(chan Result, 100)

    for {
        data := Seeder()
        msgs := Worker(data)
        results := Publisher(msgs)

        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            wg.Add(1)
            go func(){
                defer wg.Done()
                data := <- c

                // this is the updater
            }(&wg)
        }

        for _, result := range results {
            c <- result
        }
        wg.Wait()
    }
}
```

The result is that the code works up until it halts at some cycle and never moves forward. I've played with many variables, loading 100 rows instead of 10k and the result is not much different.

I also tried to pass a struct containing channels and run everything asynchronously but I've even harder time figuring out when Updater is finished so I can unblock the seeder.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to tell because your code cannot be compiled and run, and it is not clear how you use c. At least one thing is sure : wg should be passed by reference, not by value (sync.WaitGroup has the `nocopy` annotation). Then, I suppose you use c to send values to the updater. But you don’t provide their code, so I can only guess. For example, suppose that the scheduling happens such that the first 9 goroutines take all there is to read in the channel; then, the last routine is blocked forever and will never release the WaitGroup. In that case, a simple solution is to create a fresh channel in each iteration of your outermost for loop (move line 3 down two lines) and [close c](https://gobyexample.com/closing-channels) right before calling `wg.Wait()`. Your updaters must be able to handle a [read from a close channel](https://dave.cheney.net/2014/03/19/channel-axioms).

[edit] I think what you are looking for is something like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

// Result is a type
type Result struct {
    I int
}

// Seeder is a function
func Seeder() []int {
    fmt.Println("Seeding")
    return []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13}
}

// Worker is a function
func Worker(data []int) []int {
    return data
}

// Publisher is a function
func Publisher(data []int) []Result {
    var r []Result
    for i := 0; i < len(data); i++ {
        r = append(r, Result{I: data[i]})
    }
    return r
}

func updater(c chan Result, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    for _ = range c {
        // update here
        wg.Done()
    }
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    c := make(chan Result, 100)
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go updater(c, &wg)
    }

    for {
        data := Seeder()
        msgs := Worker(data)
        results := Publisher(msgs)

        wg.Add(len(results))
        for _, result := range results {
            c <- result
        }
        wg.Wait()
    }
}
```

Comment: The code wasn't meant to compile. In it's original form it's more complex. I added it to give an idea.

I've added the how I pull from the channel and also passing the WaitGroup as a pointer in this pseudo-code. The original is passing it as it supposed to.

I was trying not to create fresh channel at every cycle but it may be the easiest solution for now. Also started looking into how could I manage the whole flow through chan chan.

Comment: You create new goroutines everytime, but don't want to create new channels ? Why not ? Channels are way cheaper than goroutines.

Comment: I would love not to create goroutines every time either. Just don't know how to do it differently.

Comment: In that case, a simple way to do it would be to use the WaitGroup to monitor not the goroutines, but the messages. I added some code to illustrate this.

Comment: Alright, that's not bad. I still have to limit the amount of goroutines in the updater, but you're right. I don't have to monitor them.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you